# ListPicker doesn't show list of objects

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I created public class "cBank". This class have

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public double first_session_in { get; set; }
public double second_session_in { get; set; }
public double third_session_in { get; set; }
public double first_session_out { get; set; }
public double second_session_out { get; set; }
public double third_session_out { get; set; }
```

I created list of obj in ManiPage constructor

```
List<cBank> oListBanks = new List<cBank>();
oListBanks.Add(new cBank {Name="Alior Bank", first_session_in = ...});
oListBanks.Add(new cBank {Name="Bank BPH",first_session_in=...});
this.ListPicker.ItemsSource = oListBanks;
```

I have in my xaml code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Name="lpkBank">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
   </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I want to show only Name (of bank). rest xaml code:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Header="Bank:" FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding lpkFullBank}"
                    ItemTemplate="{Binding lpkBank}" x:Name="ListPicker" 
                    Margin="12,15,12,0" Height="110" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Now it shows only a name of classes in list picker. What should I do ?

Comment: Yes, where is your ListPicker in your Xaml code?

Comment: are you want to show name, first_session_in and all fields in listpicker

Comment: I want to show only Name (of bank).
rest xaml code:
`<toolkit:ListPicker Header="Bank:" FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding lpkFullBank}" ItemTemplate="{Binding lpkBank}"
                x:Name="ListPicker" Margin="12,15,12,0" Height="110" VerticalAlignment="Top" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I saw my mistake. `Height="110"` This was one of the reason why list didn't dropdown. 
The class is correct.

Constructor should look like this:

```
List<cBank> oListBanks = new List<cBank>();
oListBanks.Add(new cBank {Name="Alior Bank", first_session_in = ...});
oListBanks.Add(new cBank {Name="Bank BPH",first_session_in=...});
...
this.ListPicker.ItemsSource = oListBanks;
```

And XAML code should be:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ListPicker" Header="Bank:" > 
              <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="150"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Now all works properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display from your `ListPicker` you can aslo use like this
In the constructor:

```
List<cBank> oListBanks = new List<cBank>();
oListBanks.Add(new cBank {Name="Alior Bank", first_session_in = ...
oListBanks.Add(new cBank {Name="Bank BPH",first_session_in=...
```

and in your XAML code:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Key="ListPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding oListBanks , ElementName=this}" SelectionMode="Single">
     <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
     </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: I tried to paste it but it return me an error of `<ListPicker>` that I am missing assembly.

Comment: I have updated the ListPicker regarding your update. I have added `toolkit`

Comment: It return me an error of lack key. So I edited `<toolkit:ListPicker x:Key="ListPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding oListBanks , ElementName=this}">` added closing tags. But I still have error _The attachable property 'ItemTemplate' was not found in type 'ListPicker'_ `<toolkit:ListPicker x:Key="ListPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding oListBanks , ElementName=this}"><ListPicker.ItemTemplate>           <DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />              </DataTemplate></ListPicker.ItemTemplate></toolkit:ListPicker>`

Comment: I correct error by adding `toolkit`. It compile now. But when I click on listpicker nothings happening

Comment: It suppose to open a full list of object names and when I choose one name of it should stay in listpicker. Later I would try to get info of object which was chosen earlier

Comment: Don't you miss this `SelectionMode="Single"`. I have added too in the code

Comment: Still nothings happens after I click on listpicker.